# System Boot Order not found (Secure boot is not enabled)

Tags: fedora, boot, boot-loader, laptop

I have this problem http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=299306. Although this thread is not mine, I experience this problem in familiar way. Also when I put live CD, it cannot boot from the CD. Any suggestions? 
PS I am using Fedora 20. What should I do in order to boot from CD or DVD? I enabled Secure Boot and Legacy Boot Order, but nothing happens. Is it possible to install another linux distribution directly from already booted one?

`Secure boot not enabled
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults`

Comment: Are you sure your CMOS boot order choices are correct? Is CD boot really enabled? It doesn't matter what OS you are running, this is a CMOS/BIOS issue at the start of booting.

Comment: i am sure the CD boot is enabled and secure boot disabled with legacy enabled

Comment: Well then something must be broken. All you can do it try a bootable CD that is known to be good on another machine, and if it fails on yours then either your CMOS is not set up correctly or your drive is broken. It has nothing to to with Linux.