# Install Linux distribution from already booted one

Tags: debian, fedora, system-installation

I have [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183421/system-boot-order-not-found-secure-boot-is-not-enabled)  which is really annoying and I want to reset my system and install clean Linux distribution to hopefully solve the problem.

So is it possible to install new distro while I am in already booted? I have heard that there is an option to install Ubuntu directly from Windows.

Comment: Debian has debootstrap https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap which allows to do that. Of course it is distro-specific thing.

Comment: Do a search for "Linux virtual machine" or "Linux virtualization".

Comment: is it possible to erase all the data and install clean debian with that tool

Comment: I don't know about installing directly from Windows, but why not just do the normal thing, create a bootable CD and boot and install from that?

Comment: It seems that I cannot boot from CD. I tried but could not successfully booted from the disk.