# Messed up boot - System BootOrder not found

Tags: ubuntu, boot, uefi

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 17.10.

What's happening:

- I turn on PC
- Get a message that I can't read in time, something along the lines of: System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.
- PC restarts
- Endless loop

What I've tried:

- Complete fresh install with Ubuntu live usb
- Boot in with live usb and use gparted to try and set some stuff up
- boot-info - http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gSSdkpVfxt/

What I done leading up to this:

- PC was originally a Windows 10 install
- I removed Windows 10 to try Arch Linux
- I am now trying to install Ubuntu deleting my old Arch Linux installation

I believe I've messed up my booting and I am completely unsure how to fix it. Boot info asks me to change the path for the .efi file but I can't figure out how to do that. Running ThinkPad 470s.

Comment: This seems to be a reoccurring issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006545/17-10-after-upgrade-system-bootorder-not-found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183421/system-boot-order-not-found-secure-boot-is-not-enabled https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005034/ubuntu-17-system-bootorder-not-found https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1512410

Comment: It does appear manually selecting Ubuntu from the UEFI menu helps some people. But I think this is because in those cases its skipping GRUB and using EFI-stub instead and GRUB is the culprit here.

Comment: Yeah, I don't even see Ubuntu in the UEFI menu unfortunately. Thanks for the links, this is going to take some deep digging it seems.

Comment: [I managed to solve this by following the answer posted here](https://askubuntu.com/a/876153) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`BootOrder` is one of the UEFI boot variables, stored in NVRAM along with other firmware configuration (what used to be "BIOS settings").

In Linux, you can use `efibootmgr -v` to view the boot variables.

Example:

```
# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 6 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,0000,0003,0004,0005,0006
Boot0000* debian        HD(1,GPT,4fb8aadb-9507-44b5-8cab-a052a0091e2b,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\DEBIAN\GRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0001* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(1,GPT,4fb8aadb-9507-44b5-8cab-a052a0091e2b,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\REFIND\REFIND_X64.EFI)
Boot0002* UEFI: IP4 Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(107b447ad398,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.0:0<->0.0.0.0:0,0,0)..BO
Boot0003  UEFI Shell    HD(1,GPT,4fb8aadb-9507-44b5-8cab-a052a0091e2b,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\tools\shell.efi)
Boot0004* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive     BBS(129,,0x0)
Boot0005* UEFI:Removable Device BBS(130,,0x0)
Boot0006* UEFI:Network Device   BBS(131,,0x0)
```

Here I have a Debian 9 system, with two bootloaders installed: the Debian default GRUB, and the more visually-oriented rEFInd, which I've set as the primary bootloader. I also have the UEFI Shell as a boot option, although that option is currently disabled.

Note that the BootOrder lists the order in which the other BootNNNN options will be tried.

You might have a BootNNNN line that's left over from the Windows or Arch installation. Since the bootloader file it refers to no longer exists, it is going to be useless. You can use `efibootmgr -B -b NNNN` to delete it: just replace NNNN with the actual BootNNNN number you wish to delete.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I just managed to solve the issue

Comment: No problem. However, please consider documenting your solution by writing an answer yourself, so that your solution may help others with a similar problem.

Comment: I attempted to but it just got added as a comment on my OP. I followed the exact steps listed in the link for anyone else that runs into this issue!